# Ionic build android : Errors during XML parse: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-sdk-2.3, parse-android-sdk

I created a simple [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) app and when i try to build the android app using

> ionic build android

I come across this error:

```
Parsing C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\package.xml
Errors during XML parse:
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.net.MalformedURLException]
Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
Failed to download any source lists!

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.3

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

My android SDK is fully installed.there is the SDK Manager:

[image]

Is there any idea what can be wrong? I'm using Windows 10 64-bit Operating System and all the environment variables is already set:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: By any chance did you manipulated package.xml  in android SDK tools folder manually??